# how to obtain lock on django model for concurrent Operation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

i am trying to obtain locking in django model such as if user 1 is editing admin action will be disabled for user 2 once user 1 leaves the form user 2 will have access.
but still not able to find solution

```
my current model.py

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

this throws the error django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[5]' refers to 'db_locked_by', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'Mymodeladmin', or an attribute or method on 'user_admin.Mymodel'.

```
from ripplr.middleware import get_current_user
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime
import urllib2 


from django.http import request


# Create your models here.
#user_id=models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,help_text="unique id for the run")
    job_name=models.CharField(max_length=20,help_text="JOB_NAME")
    number_of_runs=models.IntegerField(help_text="overall runs")
    run_time=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    JOB_STATUS = (
        ('A', 'ACTIVE'),
        ('R', 'RUNNING'),
        ('F', 'FAILED'),
        ('IN', 'INACTIVE')
        )

    status= models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=JOB_STATUS, blank=True, default='A', help_text='SET JOB STATUS')
    lock_time=datetime.datetime.now()
    #db_locked_by =models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,blank=True)
    db_locked_by=get_current_user()
#


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.id,self.job_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Job-Detail', args=[str(self.job_name)])

class Meta:
    ordering=["-run_time"]
```

Comment: You can use a locked attribute in your model and lock it with `select for update` using some helper methods. Check api documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update

Comment: thanks form the reply.but i am still not able to understand how to disable the buttons when doing so..can you please provide a sample code if you have any

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create some simple lock mechanism. You can add two fields to the model: lock_user and lock_dt. Each time a user starts editing you set lock_user to the user and lock_dt to the current time. When editing is finished you just clear the fields. If another user tries to edit the instance you check if the fields are empty. You can have some protection against locking the file forever - you can remove/ignore every lock that is older than x minutes.

There's also a django-locking library on [github](https://github.com/RobCombs/django-locking) you can use for that although I'm not sure if it is up-to-date.

---

Below you'll find an example of how you can lock an object so no other person can edit the same object in Django admin.
There's a 30 minutes lock when a user starts editing an object. Other users won't see the form buttons - they'll see a message "Object is locked" instead.
It's based on overwriting two methods of ModelAdmin class and the change_view template.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    JOB_STATUS = (
        ('A', 'ACTIVE'),
        ('R', 'RUNNING'),
        ('F', 'FAILED'),
        ('IN', 'INACTIVE')
        )
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    number_of_runs=models.IntegerField()
    run_time=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    status= models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=JOB_STATUS, blank=True, default='A')
    locked_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    locked_dt = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)


# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Make the fields with lock information read-only
    readonly_fields = ('locked_by', 'locked_dt')
    # Override the template with you own
    change_form_template = 'mymodel_change_form.html'

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Release the lock when saving the object
        obj.locked_by = None
        obj.locked_dt = None
        super(MyModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def change_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        # Mark the object as locked when the user starts editing
        object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=object_id)
        if request.method == 'GET':
            # Set a new lock if there's no lock or the user set the lock or the lock was set more than 30m ago
            if object.locked_by is None or object.locked_by == request.user or \
                timezone.now() - object.locked_dt > timedelta(minutes=30):
                object.locked_by = request.user
                object.locked_dt = timezone.now()
                object.save()
            extra_context = extra_context or {}
            extra_context['is_locked'] = object.locked_by != request.user

        return super(MyModel, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)


# templates/mymodel_change_form.html

{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load admin_modify %}
{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
{% if is_locked %}<strong>Object is locked</strong>
{% else %}{% submit_row %}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: the library no longer supports the recent django version and i am still looking for a concrete solution to the issue

Comment: I don't think you need a library for that as the whole requirement you gave sounds quite simple. What do you think about the idea with the two fields? It's really easy to code that.

Comment: thanks roman , I am very new to django , i still dont get it how will i set the lock , i have tried few ways but nothing has worked, the main issue is to disable the admin actions for other users. i have tried has_permission but it locks it completely. if you have any sample code it would help a lot

Comment: Hi i am trying the method you suggested but unable to get the current user name please suggest on my admin.py

Comment: I'm not really sure where you have the problem with getting user name. Find the instance of request (it's self.request in view classes or it's passed as a request parameter) and you can get the user in request.user. The best way to implement the lock functionality on the admin site would be to overwrite get_form method of the ModelAdmin.

Comment: Hi Roman thank for replying,the actual issue happen when i need to know who has opened the django model instance and lock it on his name till it is open and disable the field from admin panel.the issue sitll is not resolved for me

Comment: The class definition of the model is no the right place to determine who is updating the instance. You should work in the admin.py file with ModelAdmin classes and overwriting its methods.Let me find some time - I'll send you some simple example of how you can implement such a functionality.

Comment: Hey, sorry you had to wait so long - finally found some time today and you can check if the solution works for you!